# Is OpenCV GigE Vision and GenIcam Compatible

Tags: opencv, camera, gige-sdk, genicam

Can OpenCV seamlessly interact with all cameras that comply with these standards

Answer (score 1):

No it cannot. You need something called a GenTLProducer in order to interact with your camera. Normally your vendor's SDK comes with it. Alternatively, you can use the one from Baumer [Here](https://www.baumer.com/de/de/produktubersicht/industriekameras-bildverarbeitung/software/baumer-gapi-sdk/c/14174) or from Stemmer Imaging [Here](https://www.commonvisionblox.com/en/cvb-download/).
Another option is to use [harvesters](https://github.com/genicam/harvesters/), which is an open source project that aims to do this. Although you need a GenTLProducer for that as well.